# Constraints, generic variables and arithmetic operators

Tags: c#, .net

I’d like to declare a generic class *Simple* where a method called *Addition* would take two generic variables and add them together using *+* operator. I thought I could accomplish this by giving class Simple the following constraint:

```
class Simple<T> where T: int
{
    public T Addition(T firstInt, T secondInt)
    {
        return firstInt + secondInt;
    }
}
```

I suspect error has something to do with generics only having  the following five types of constraints  - *ClassName, class, struct,InterfaceName, new()*? Thus, why don’t generics also support *StructureName* constraint type? That way we would be able to apply arithmetic operators on generic variables?!

thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `StructName` constraint wouldn't make sense, since you cannot inherit from value types.

If you had something like `class Simple<T> where T : int` you could **only** instantiate `Simple<T>` with `T = int`, no type inherits from `int` or any other value type for that matter.

C# (the CLR) lacks what other languages know as [type classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class), one popular mechanism to handle operator overloading without hard-coded compiler mechanics (like in C#).

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in constraining a Generic type to a specific struct, since struct types cannot be inherited.  This would be identical to writing:

```
class Simple
{
    public int Addition(int firstInt, int secondInt)
    {
        return firstInt + secondInt;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, with support for an [IArithmetic interface](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94264/arithmetic-types-like-int-double-decimal-should-implement-iarithmetic-t), generic types with mathematical operations are difficult to support.  If you want to see one approach for generic-based mathmetical operators, look to the [Generic Operators in MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html).

Answer (score 1):

You constrain `T` to `int`. This is no sensible thing to do, as there is only one int type; so you could directly want to write `int` if you want `int`.

If you do not constrain `T`, you cannot use the `+` operator, since there is no `+` operator defined on object.

C# generics are not C++ templates.