# Generic sorting in c#, type constraints

Tags: c#, oop, types, constraints

a lot of googling and still no answer.

**What's the problem:**
I'm trying to implement generic sort methods to sort custom objects and also value types as int, uint etc. There is no problem with quick sort, heap sort etc. moreover I found counting sort impossible to do, because of it's specificity. All data must be non negative and integer.

**Question:**

```
where T : struct..
```

don't give needed unary operators "+-" and as I know there's no possibility to force it. How to set proper type constraints, or how to force T to have operators "+-"?

```
public interface ISortMethod<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T[] Sort(T[] tablica);
}

public class CountingSort<T> : ISortMethod<T>
    where T : IComparable<T> 
{
    public T[] Sort(T[] tablica)
    {
        T[] tab2 = (T[])tablica.Clone();
        return Sortuj(tab2);
    }

    private T[] Sortuj(T[] tab)
    {
        T min = tab[0];
        T max = tab[0];

        T[] res = new T[tab.Length];

        //< 0 wczesniejsza this
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
        {
            if (tab[i].CompareTo(max) > 0)
                max = tab[i];

            if (tab[i].CompareTo(min) < 0)
                min = tab[i];
        }

        T[] cData = new T[**(max - min)** + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
            **cData[tab[i] - min] += 1**;

        for (int i = 1; i < cData.Length; i++)
            cData[i] += cData[i - 1];

        for (int i = tab.Length-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            res[cData[tab[i] - min] - 1] = tab[i];
            cData[tab[i] - min]--;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constraints, generic variables and arithmetic operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254085/constraints-generic-variables-and-arithmetic-operators)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define a generic that implements the + operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598341/define-a-generic-that-implements-the-operator)

Comment: Is there a specific sort algorithm you're trying to implement here?

Answer (score 0):

You can't force generic type parameter to have *any* operators, using C# generic constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `Comparer<T>`, or your own `IComparer<T>` implementation, or `Comparison<T>`; these tell you what order two objects are in by returning an integer.  You compare the integer with the usual operators; if the integer is negative, the first object is smaller, if it's zero, they're equal, and if it's positive, the first object is larger.

Since you have to use the comparer or comparison anyway, you might as well just use the framework methods that take one of these as a parameter.